# Create makefile which iterate through directory

Tags: c, gcc, makefile

```
                         $project
                            |
     +------------+----------------+----------------+
     |            |                |                |
   gestore/     tipoA/           tipoB/            shared/
     |            |                |                 |
     +            +                +                 +
     |            |                |        +--------|------------------+
  gestore.c     tipoA.c          tipoB.c/   funzioni.c/.h sem.c/.h gF.c./
```

Hello, I would like to create a makefile for this project, which does these commands:

Step 1 in SHARED FOLDER:

```
gcc -c -o gestioneFile gestioneFile.c
gcc -c -o sem sem.c
gcc -c -o funzioni funzioni.c
```

Step 2 in  tipoA FOLDER:

```
gcc -o tipoA tipoA.c ../shared/funzioni ../shared/sem ../shared/gestioneFile
```

Step 3 in  tipoB FOLDER:

```
gcc -o tipoB tipoB.c ../shared/funzioni ../shared/sem ../shared/gestioneFile
```

Step 4 in gestore FOLDER:

```
gcc -o gestore gestore.c ../shared/funzioni ../shared/sem ../shared/gestioneFile

./gestore
```

This is my makefile but it doesn't works:

```
#Makefile

cc=gcc

./gestore/gestore: ./shared/gestioneFile.o ./shared/sem.o ./shared/funzioni.o ./tipoA/tipoA.o ./tipoB/tipoB.o ./gestore/gestore.o
    ./gestore/gestore

./shared/gestioneFile.o: 
    cc -c -o ./shared/gestioneFile ./shared/gestioneFile.c

./shared/sem.o:
    cc -c -o ./shared/sem ./shared/sem.c

./shared/functions.o: 
    cc -c -o ./shared/funzioni ./shared/funzioni.c

./tipoA/tipoA.o: ./shared/gestioneFile.o ./shared/sem.o ./shared/funzioni.o 
    cc -o ./tipoA/tipoA ./tipoA/tipoA.c ./shared/funzioni ./shared/sem ./shared/gestioneFile 

./tipoB/tipoB.o: ./shared/gestioneFile.o ./shared/sem.o ./shared/funzioni.o 
    cc -o ./tipoB/tipoB ./tipoB/tipoB.c ../shared/funzioni ../shared/sem ../shared/gestioneFile

./gestore/gestore.o: ./shared/gestioneFile.o ./shared/sem.o ./shared/funzioni.o 
    cc -o ./gestore/gestore ./gestore/gestore.c ./shared/funzioni ./shared/sem ./shared/gestioneFile
```

EDIT:
@HardcoreHenry This is my makefile now, but it gives the error: ***** Missing separator.**

```
#Makefile

cc=gcc

./gestore/gestore:  ./shared/gestioneFile.o ./shared/sem.o ./shared/funzioni.o ./tipoA/tipoA.o ./tipoB/tipoB.o ./gestore/gestore.o
    ./gestore/gestore

./shared/gestioneFile.o: 
    cc -c -o ./shared/gestioneFile.o ./shared/gestioneFile.c

./shared/sem.o:
    cc -c -o ./shared/sem.o ./shared/sem.c

./shared/funzioni.o: 
    cc -c -o ./shared/funzioni.o ./shared/funzioni.c

./tipoA/tipoA.o: ./shared/gestioneFile.o ./shared/sem.o ./shared/funzioni.o 
    cc -o ./tipoA/tipoA.o ./tipoA/tipoA.c ./shared/funzioni.o ./shared/sem.o ./shared/gestioneFile.o

./tipoB/tipoB.o: ./shared/gestioneFile.o ./shared/sem.o ./shared/funzioni.o 
    cc -o ./tipoB/tipoB.o ./tipoB/tipoB.c ../shared/funzioni.o ../shared/sem.o ../shared/gestioneFile.o

./gestore/gestore.o: ./shared/gestioneFile.o ./shared/sem.o ./shared/funzioni.o 
    cc -o ./gestore/gestore.o ./gestore/gestore.c ./shared/funzioni.o ./shared/sem.o ./shared/gestioneFile.o
```

SOLVED (even if the first rule does not execute the file):

```
./gestore/gestore: ./shared/gestioneFile.o  ./shared/sem.o  ./shared/funzioni.o ./tipoA/tipoA   ./tipoB/tipoB   ./gestore/gestore
    ./gestore/gestore

./shared/gestioneFile.o:
    gcc -c -o ./shared/gestioneFile ./shared/gestioneFile.c

./shared/sem.o:
    gcc -c -o ./shared/sem ./shared/sem.c

./shared/funzioni.o: 
    gcc -c -o ./shared/funzioni ./shared/funzioni.c

./tipoA/tipoA:  ./shared/gestioneFile.o ./shared/sem.o  ./shared/funzioni.o 
    gcc -o ./tipoA/tipoA ./tipoA/tipoA.c ./shared/gestioneFile ./shared/sem ./shared/funzioni 

./tipoB/tipoB: ./shared/gestioneFile.o  ./shared/sem.o  ./shared/funzioni.o 
    gcc -o ./tipoB/tipoB ./tipoB/tipoB.c ./shared/gestioneFile ./shared/sem ./shared/funzioni

./gestore/gestore: ./shared/gestioneFile.o  ./shared/sem.o  ./shared/funzioni.o 
    gcc -o ./gestore/gestore ./gestore/gestore.c ./shared/gestioneFile ./shared/sem ./shared/funzioni
```

Comment: You've left out the most vital and crucial part of your question - how does the Makefile not work? Give details!

Comment: This line - `cc=gcc` - does nothing by the way. You maybe meant `CC=gcc` but then you'd have also used `$(CC)` rather than `cc` elsewhere

Comment: It looks like you are missing the extension to all your '-o' options:
`cc -c -o ./shared/sem ./shared/sem.c` should be `cc -c -o ./shared/sem.o ./shared/sem.c`

Comment: @ChrisTurner cc: error: ../shared/funzioni. No such file or Directory cc: error: ../shared/gF. No such file or Directory cc: error: ../shared/sem. No such file or Directory

Comment: @Nonyme I'm pretty sure that the -o is not necessary because if I do the command manually it works.

Comment: When you say works, it likely does not generate an error message, but also does not generate the `.o` file...

Comment: Also, your `cc` command is run from project's root directory, so there should be no `../` prefix in file paths

Comment: Offtopic note: your makefile writing approach is totally unmaintainable. Consider using template rules, and build shared or static library for stuff in `shared` directory

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following line would give you those errors:

```
./tipoA/tipoA.o: ./shared/gestioneFile.o ./shared/sem.o ./shared/funzioni.o 
    cc -o ./tipoA/tipoA ./tipoA/tipoA.c ./shared/funzioni ./shared/sem ./shared/gestioneFile
```

First, you are outputting to `./tipoA/tipoA` instead of `./tipoA/tipoA.o` as @Nonyme pointed out.  This would not cause your compile failure though.

What would cause a failure is that it is trying to use `./shared/funzioni` as an input -- that file does not exist.   (notice the makefile target depends on `./shared/funzioni.o`, which must be built before this recipe is invoked, but it does not generate `shared/funzioni` (without the `.o`)

You need to add the `.o`'s to the target and sources of your cc commands.

I would also suggest using `$(CC)`, and lookup [automatic variables](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Automatic-Variables.html) -- specifically `$@` and `$^` for your recipes.  Much neater and less error prone that way.

```
./tipoA/tipoA.o: ./shared/gestioneFile.o ./shared/sem.o ./shared/funzioni.o 
    $(CC) -o $@ $^
```

Comment: I edited the question, now it gives me the error: *** Missing Separators.

Comment: I believe that's the error Make outputs when you put spaces in front of a recipe instead of tabs.

Comment: See https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Error-Messages.html for more info on this error

Comment: Also, the first target/recipe you have seems very odd -- you have a rule to build `./gestore/gestore`, and it's only recipe is to call `./gestore/gestore` (which is either out of date, or doesn't exist).

Comment: In the first rule I would like to execute the file "gestore" into the directory called "gestore"

Comment: The first rule is the only one which doesn't works. All the files are compiled (I edited the question with the solution) but the file "gestore" is not executed.

Comment: Your first rule should likely be: `all: ./gestore/gestore; ./gestore/gestore` and then have the `./gestore/gestore` rule just build the file.